Dissolving relationship between two objects causes browser refresh to throw 500 error
I am working in Python/Flask
I am working on a project at work and I'm not 100% sure why this happens, but essentially I have a table, and in one of the rows there is a button to assign one object to another, basic one-to-one relationship. That part works fine, but when I do the opposite, and unassign the object and try to refresh the page I am getting a 500 error. There is a template tag in place that should prevent this, but for some reason it doesn't. The template tag looks like this:
{% if kp.kitrequest_id != None %}
<a class='assigned_engagement' href='{{url_for('kit_request_blueprint.kit_request_detail', ticketnum=kp.kit_request.ticket_number)}}'>{{kp.kit_request.cover_term}}</a>
{% endif %}

The unassign takes place on the forms submit, so I am thinking this may just be a case of some weird async behavior? But im not sure because it doesnt matter how long I wait, if I unassign the object, and then refresh at any point after that it throws the error NoneType has no attribute 'cover_term' but nothing I seem to do fixes that. Is it just that the data isnt getting refreshed on the table or something? This is a project for work so I'm trying to keep the actual code to a minimum, but if more information is needed I can provide what I can
I've tried refreshing the table with Javascript, and just redirecting to the same page after the submit has finished, but the refresh continues to crash the page. It's worth noting that if I just navigate to a different page, and then back to the original page, the page then loads fine, which leads me to believe that its just a data refresh problem, like the page isn't pulling the latest data from the database, but i'm not sure.
